# Heterogeneous Data Over TCP/IP

Tags: matlab, tcp

I need to send and receive heterogeneous data from a Matlab client to a server.  The data includes 32-bit integers and 64-bit IEEE floats.  Remember that TCP/IP only understands characters, so I need to pack this data together into a contiguous array to be clocked out.  Then after receiving the response, I need to extract the byte data from the incoming character array and form it into Matlab types.  Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: "...TCP/IP only understands characters..." - that's not true. TCP/IP (actually we're only talking about TCP here), will send any bits you want... the encoding (sometimes "characters") doesn't matter one bit. If you can pack the data into a byte array and write it to a TCP socket, you'll be fine. Sounds like you need a protocol for how things are packed and unpacked (serialized/deserialized). There are many formats with libraries available for serializing data. To name a few: gRPC, MessagePack, BSON, Protobuf, Thrift, XML, JSON... the list goes on.

Comment: I have to disagree.  From the TCP RFC:  "The TCP is able to transfer a continuous stream of octets in each direction between its users by packaging some number of octets into segments for transmission through the internet system."  So TCP assumes the data will come in an array of octets, or bytes--or characters, for the x86 architecture.  In a language like C or Forth, assembling (or serializing or multiplexing) even a 64-bit (or 80-bit, in Forth) IEEE real into an array of characters is trivial.  But in Matlab it isn't.  I've created a concise, dependable method that suits my application.

Comment: Octets and bytes are equivalent yes. But characters are not. Characters are bytes that are arranged in a particular order and method - i.e. encoded. TCP cares nothing of encoding. It just delivers bytes - encoded or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The generic term for turning heterogeneous data into a stream of bytes or characters is **serializing** (and the reverse, **deserializing**).

Two widely-used formats for serializing data into text characters are **XML** and **JSON**.

If you search the Mathworks site for any of those terms, or search this site for any of those terms together with `[matlab]` you'll find plenty of libraries and code examples.

Or since R2016b, MATLAB actually has built-in functions for serializing to / deserializing from JSON: [`jsonencode`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) and [`jsondecode`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html).